# Как реализовать в CSS анимацию заливки плавно увеличивающегося круга

Tags: css

Как можно реализовать анимацию смены цвета фона как на гифке? Интересует именно круговая плавная заливка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: я пытался сделать с помощью `box-shadow`

```
.wave {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    right: 40px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #212121;
    transition: box-shadow .3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
}

.wave.active {
    background: #212121;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 9999px #212121;
}
```

и это работает, но изучив данный подход узнал что это не best practice, т.к. могут быть странные эффекты при добавлении дополнительных анимаций.

Comment: Что Вы уже делали, и в чём конкретно возникли затруднения? Отредактируйте вопрос - добавьте разметку-стили-скрипты наработок.

Comment: @UModeL отредактировал

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('.box__button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('.box').classList.toggle("box--animation");
})
```

```css
.box {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.box__button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #8dce91;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}

.box::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 35px;
    top: 35px;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #000;
    transform: translate(50%, -50%);
    transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
}

.box--animation::before {
    z-index: -1;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
    <div class='box'>
        <button class='box__button'>Click</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Подправил реализацию